# How do I change the color of the bars in my graph in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the code importing the data and plotting it but all the bars are purple and I want to change up the colors for each.  Another issue I noticed is that it shows the file location on the graph and I don't want it on there.

```
set title "Accuracy Plot for the FASP" 
set xlabel "Fucntion"
set ylabel "(%)"
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key fixed right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox
set style increment default
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  autojustify
set xtics  norangelimit 
set xtics   ()
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set x2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set yrange [ 0 : 100 ] noreverse writeback
set y2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set zrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
plot 'C:\Users\John\Desktop\Mystery Assignment for Lomotey\FASP.dat' using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
```

Answer (score 0):

...in case you haven't found yet a solution yourself...
For example, you could add a column to your data defining the color as hexadecimal number, e.g. `0xff0000` for red. Then in the plot command with `linecolor rgb variable` it will take the color from column 4 (actually, the last column of `1:3:4: xtic(2)`, not counting `xtic(2)`.)
In order to remove the file name as legend you can add `notitle` in the plot command or in a previous line `unset key`.

If you prefer to give color names instead of color numbers, check this [gnuplot: apply colornames from datafile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736522/7295599)

**Code:**

```
### change color of boxes
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  One     1  0xff0000
2  Two     4  0x00ff00
3  Three   9  0x0000ff
4  Four   16  0xff00ff
5  Five   25  0xffff00
6  Six    36  0x00ffff
EOD

set boxwidth 0.7
plot $Data u 1:3:4:xtic(2) w boxes fill solid 1.0 lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]