# How to use color palette indexes for gnuplot box charts?

Tags: gnuplot

I try to map some index to a color of a defined palette. But the defined palette does not seem to get used.

Given a files `data.txt`:

```
11
22
33
44
```

The gnuplot commands:

```
set nokey
set grid
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
set yrange [0:]
set palette model RGB maxcolors 7
set palette defined (0 'dark-violet', 1 'skyblue', 2 'dark-yellow', 3 'dark-green', 4 'dark-red', 5 'coral', 6 'green', 7 'purple')
plot 'data.txt' using 0:1:(column(0)+1) with boxes linecolor variable
```

This gives:
[image: gnuplot box graph]

This does not match the defined palette. How can I make gnuplot use the defined palette here with the index and color names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up:

```
set nokey
set grid
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:]
set palette defined (0 'dark-violet', 1 'skyblue', 2 'dark-yellow', 3 'dark-green', 4 'dark-red', 5 'coral', 6 'green', 7 'purple')
set cbrange [0 : 7]
unset colorbox
plot 'data.txt' using 0:1:(0.5):(column(0)) with boxes linecolor palette
```

The solution was to add the box width `(0.5)` in the plot row and to use `cbrange` and `linecolor palette`:

[image: gnuplot colored boxes]

Comment: if you had found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/55729706/7295599 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658674/7295599
it certainly would have helped...

Comment: The first one would have been helpful, but does not seem to use a palette.