# how to find the number of colors for labeling in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to put labels in a plot using gnuplot. For example, I need to label "Object 1" as blue:

```
set label 6 at 313,200 'Object 1' center rotate by 70 front tc ls 3
```

But `3` is not the kind of blue which I need. There are many different websites that show corresponding colors and numbers in gnuplot but for labeling the numbers of colors are not relevant to gnuplot color numbers. Where can I find the relevant different color numbers for labels?

Comment: Run the command `test` in gnuplot, or you can set any RGB color value, see `help rgbcolor`.

Comment: gnuplot has 111 predefined colors, type `show colornames` or see them here visualized: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599, or as Michael O. says "mix" your color red, e.g. `"0xff0000"` according to the scheme `0xRRGGBB`. Set your textcolor with `...tc rgb 0xff0000`

Comment: @theozh, Michael O Thank you guys. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just, for the sake of not letting this question appear unanswered:

gnuplot has 111 predefined colors, type `show colornames` or see them here: [predefined gnuplot colors visualized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599), or as Michael O. says "mix" your color red, e.g. `0xff0000` according to the scheme `0xRRGGBB`. Set your textcolor with ...`tc rgb 0xff0000`. You even can add transparency according to the scheme `0xAARRGGBB` where `AA` is the alpha channel, `00` is opaque, `ff` is fully transparent.