# gnuplot histogram with box shading

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

My goal is to create a histogram with gnuplot 5.4 boxes, and have each box shaded with a specific RGB value (for testing purposes it is "green" but will be #RRGGBB in final data set)

My data looks like this:

```
5.800507    1   1   green
121.810653  6   1   green
133.411668  41  1   green
```

1st column - X value,
2nd column - Y value,
3rd column - box width,
4th column - rgb

This works and produces the expected graph output:

```
plot "data.out" using 1:2:3 with boxes
```

If I change the plot commend to this, it fails with the error "x range is invalid" and also gives the warning "Skipping data file with no valid points":

```
plot "data.out" using 1:2:3:4 with boxes lc rgb variable
```

I've found a number of examples in blogs for doing this with gnuplot 4.2, but all of them fail with the same "x range is invalid" error under 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnuplot cannot (yet?) use a color name as input for variable color.
If you want to use a color name (as string) for `lc var ...`, check the following workaround:  [gnuplot: apply colornames from datafile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658674/7295599)

For your test case: simply change `green` to `0x00ff00`.

**Code:**

```
### variable color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
5.800507    1   1   0x00ff00
121.810653  6   1   0x00ff00
133.411668  41  1   0x00ff00
EOD

set style fill solid 1.0

plot $Data using 1:2:3:4 with boxes lc rgb variable
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The gnuplot development version (5.5) provides a function `rgbcolor("colorname")`, but this function is not yet in 5.4. So in 5.5 you could use `plot $Data using 1:2:3:(rgbcolor(stringcolumn(4))) with boxes lc rgb variable`