# How to specify fill color and border line color from column data in gnuplot

Tags: plot, colors, gnuplot, palette, color-palette

I want to plot my data using boxxyerror bar in gnuplot

data looks like this:

```
#x  y   fill-color   border-color
2   2      0.50          1.00
8   2      0.25          0.50
8   8      0.40          0.40
2   8      0.50          0.50
```

column 1 gives x cordinates, column 2 gives y cordinates
column 3 gives border color and column 4 gives fill color
I will be placing squares of side 2 at all these points effectively.
Color is chosen from a palette with a range [0.0:1.0]

The plot will look something like this(this is just sample):
[image]

if I was taking only fill colour from data I will plot it using boxxyerrorbar as

```
plot "data.txt" u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):3 with boxxyerrorbar fs solid lc palette
```

if I was taking only border colour from data I will plot it using boxxyerrorbar as

```
plot "data.txt" u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):4 with boxxyerrorbar fs border lc palette
```

using palette for both is also fine:

```
plot "data.txt" u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):4 with boxxyerrorbar fs border lc palette fc palette
```

But we are using column 4 for both colours, but I need them to be read from columns 3 and 4 separately. Or at least I would like to have something like one colour is a function of the same column data using for palette, like:

```
plot "data.txt" u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):4 with boxxyerrorbar fs border lc (column(4)*0.5) fc palette
```

More generally, I want to use numbers in some columns to be used for determining the colour of border or fill color in my plot, I could be able to do something like:

```
plot "data.txt" u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):4 with boxxyerrorbar fs border lc (2*(column 5)-0.60) fc (palette * 0.24)
```

I need some kind of solution to this problem please help me.

Finally, this Is the plot I want to make(but basic requirement covers in above question). This is a phase diagram, grey borders are data I have, red borders means it's extrapolated!
[image]
It was done by plotting two files which store fill color and border color separately(Inspired by @theozh 's answer)-

Comment: Does the color have to be from a palette? What is your actual palette? How many colors?

Comment: not necessarily, I was trying something else as well, for fill color I take colour from palette itself. And for border colour I define certain line types previously with my required colours and call that here, but now the line types need to be determined from the same column(palette)-- if last column has values like 0.1,0.2,0.3 etc, I defined line types 1,2,3 with my required colours and was trying to give line type as : with boxxyerror fs border lc ($3 * 10) fc palette.. but this is also only giving error. any way border colour needs to be different in each line.

Answer (score 2):

The first "quick and dirty" solution which comes to my mind is to plot the boxes twice:
once with variable color fill and the second time empty for the border with variable color.
Plotting twice should work the same with a palette.

Hopefully there will be a better solution for this.

**Script:**

```
### different colors for fill and border from datafile
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#x  y   fill-color  border-color
2   2   0x0000ff    0x000000
8   2   0x00ff00    0xffaa00
8   8   0xffffff    0xff0000
2   8   0xffff00    0x0000ff
EOD

set size square
set offsets 1,1,1,1
set style fill solid 1.0 border lc rgb var
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):3 w boxxy fs solid lc rgb var, \
        '' u 1:2:(1.0):(1.0):4 w boxxy fs empty lc rgb var lw 2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Based on the comments and modified question, here is another suggestion.
My understanding is that you want to have **only one** number to define the colors for *fill* **and** *border* of a square. In your example you only have 2 colors for fill and 2 colors for border, which makes 4 possible combinations in total.

The example below expands this to 16 colors each for border and fill, which makes it 256 combinations.
Check the table `$myColors` and select a color for the fill and a color for the border. Add the corresponding numbers and put the result into your datafile as third column.
For example:

```
black  fill=0 + red  border=16    -->  16
green  fill=2 + grey border=128   --> 130
yellow fill=4 + blue border=48    -->  52
```

You can easily change the colors or expand it accordingly to many more combinations. By the way, you can find predefined gnuplot colors by typing `show colors` or [here as an overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599).

Furthermore, I noticed that plotting borders of adjacent squares will "overwrite" each other in the graph, i.e. visibility of a border depends on the plotting sequence. In order to be independent of this, I would suggest to plot larger and smaller filled squares instead of bordered squares.

Another suggestion: instead of going for logscale (making the size for your boxes difficult) you can stay in linear scale and simply adjust the tic-labels via `xtic()` and `ytic()`, check `help xticlabels`.

All these are just suggestions, since I might not know all the background and details for your specific plotting case.

**Script:** (only 5x5 table for illustration)

```
### define fill and border by a single number
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# x  y   colors
 1   1   128
 1   2   128
 1   3   128
 1   4   16
 1   5   52
 2   1   128
 2   2   128
 2   3   128
 2   4   16
 2   5   16
 3   1   130
 3   2   128
 3   3   128
 3   4   16
 3   5   241
 4   1   130
 4   2   130
 4   3   128
 4   4   16
 4   5   16
 5   1   18
 5   2   18
 5   3   130
 5   4   16
 5   5   16
EOD

# color   fill  border   name
$myColors <<EOD
0x000000     0       0   black
0xff0000     1      16   red
0x00ff00     2      32   green
0x0000ff     3      48   blue
0xffff00     4      64   yellow
0xffa500     5      80   orange
0xff00ff     6      96   magenta
0x00ffff     7     112   cyan 
0xc0c0c0     8     128   grey
0xd3d3d3     9     144   light-grey
0xa0a0a0    10     160   dark-grey
0xc080ff    11     176   purple
0x00c000    12     192   web-green
0x0080ff    13     208   web-blue
0xffb6c1    14     224   light-pink
0xffffff    15     240   white
EOD

fillColor(n)   = int(word($myColors[int(n)%16+1],1))
borderColor(n) = int(word($myColors[(int(n)/16)%16+1],1))   # integer division!

set size square
set xrange [:] noextend
set yrange [:] noextend
set tics out
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:2:(0.50):(0.50):(borderColor($3)): \
             xtic(sprintf("%g",2**($1+1))):ytic(sprintf("%g",2**($2+1))) \
             w boxxy lc rgb var, \
        '' u 1:2:(0.46):(0.46):(fillColor($3)) w boxxy lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks fine. But what if I want to do this from a single column? Say I have 0.1,0.2,0.3 in col3. For the filling, I use it directly. For border color, I need different colors but derived from this same column of data something like f($3) of f(palette). Because if I could multiply this by 10=> 1,2,3  which I can assign my required border colors. Another way was to define line type 1,2,3 with my required border colors, and when plotting the border, I again use this converted column 3 value as line type - fs border lt ($3*10) | lt (palette*10) | lt (column(3)*10)  - nothing works

Comment: or is there a way to have two palettes? I get data from the same column but use a different user-defined palette.

Comment: I made a new data file for border color! writing one more column for border color data seemed tedious.

Comment: @fahd which two palettes would you like? What is your gnuplot version?

Comment: version is 5.4 -- Palettes, I mean I define myself, 'set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'black', 1 'green')'. With the temporary solution, keeping border line color in another I have got the plot I imagined. I will add this with question now!

Answer (score 0):

I got a temporary solution to the actual problem I had.

I defined my palette as

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 'black', 0.3 'red', 0.6 'grey', 1 'green')
```

stored my border colors in 'border.dat' and fill color in 'fill.dat'
[image]

[image]

and plotted them like this:

```
plot for [i=1:13] "fill.dat" u 1:(2**(i+1)):($1/2.0**0.5):($1*2.0**0.5):(2**(i+1)/2.0**0.5):(2**(i+1)*2.0**0.5):i+1  with boxxyerror fc palette,\
for [i=1:13] "border.dat" u 1:(2**(i+1)):($1/2.0**0.5):($1*2.0**0.5):(2**(i+1)/2.0**0.5):(2**(i+1)*2.0**0.5):i+1  with boxxyerror fs empty lc palette lw 2
```

( sorry, cordinates and box dimensions will appear messy because I am plotting on log scale)

and Finally got this! (red borders means it is extrapolated[which I don't have data for])
[image]

Comment: OK, so you basically have only 2 fill colors and 2 border colors, but want to address all 4 combination by a single number. I think you can have this without palette and extra table files. By the way, why is `2**14=16348` in your plot? On my computer it is 16384.

Comment: Lol! I wrote it by hand, anyway that makes no visible difference since the actual difference is small

Comment: So you got any solution for this @theozh? I was trying to make color for border from color of fill itself something like, (palette * 2.0) or (column(I) * 2.0) etc.. but that options do not seem to work